# Redirecting stdout and stderr in background process to files in powershell

Tags: powershell, stream, stdout, stderr

I'm trying to redirect stdout to `.\output\worker01.log` and stderr to `.\output\worker01-error.log`. It works if i run the command in the shell:

```
PS Q:\mles\etl-i_test> .\worker\bin\win32\php.exe -q -c .\worker\conf\php.ini .\worker\bin\os-independant\logfilefilter\logfilefilter.php -f .\worker\worker01\conf\logfilefilter-worker01.xml 2> .\output\worker01-error.log > .\output\worker01.log
```

The `worker01.log` and `worker01-error.log` are written to the output directory.

However I need it in a powershell script as multiple background processes. There can be n worker processes, in my testcase there are 8 workers. This is how I call it:

```
$strPath = get-location
$workers = get-childitem -Path worker -Filter worker*
foreach ($worker in $workers)
{
  Write-Host "Start $worker in background"

  $block = {& $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] $args[3] $args[4] $args[5] $args[6] $args[7] $args[8] $args[9] $args[10]}
  start-job -scriptblock $block -argumentlist `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\win32\php.exe", `
    "-q", `
    "-c", `
    "$strPath\worker\conf\php_win32.ini", `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\os-independant\logfilefilter\logfilefilter.php", `
    "-f", `
    "$strPath\worker\$worker\conf\logfilefilter-$worker.xml", `
    "2>", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker-error.log", `
    ">", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker.log"
}
```

If I start the script, I can see 8 php and powershell processes spawn, which immediately disappear. There are no log files in the output directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put the redirection characters (">" and "2>") in the argumentlist. They need to be in the scriptblock.

```
  $block = {& $args[0] $args[1] $args[2] $args[3] $args[4] $args[5] $args[6] 2> $args[7] > $args[8]}
  start-job -scriptblock $block -argumentlist `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\win32\php.exe", `
    "-q", `
    "-c", `
    "$strPath\worker\conf\php_win32.ini", `
    "$strPath\worker\bin\os-independant\logfilefilter\logfilefilter.php", `
    "-f", `
    "$strPath\worker\$worker\conf\logfilefilter-$worker.xml", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker-error.log", `
    "$strPath\output\$worker.log"
```

It works like this.

Comment: Did you just answer your own question?